# Understanding the loop disassembly

Tags: disassembly, binary-analysis

Here is the code of loop that I'm trying to understand the disassembly of it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   int i, arr[50], num;

   printf("\nEnter no of elements :");
   cin >> num;

   //Reading values into Array
   printf("\nEnter the values :");
   for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    cin >> arr[i];

   return 0;
}
```

And this is the disassembly:
[image]

Can you explain me the highlighted part? what is `Var_D8` is used for? Why compiler shifted left the `edx`?

Comment: SHL EDX,2 is basically multiplying EDX's value by 4.

Comment: @DominikAntal for what purpose?

Comment: I am not sure. However I suspect that this might be some compiler optimization/alignment for the array. Can you tell us the compiler and it's parameters you used? Will the SHL instruction be present if you recompile this code with `arr` beeing a byte array? You could also attach a dynamic debugger (Ollydbg) and see what is happening exactly by stepping trough your code.

Comment: The key to understanding this is the `lea` opcode - eax gets the *address*, not the *content*, of that stack variable. This is the start of your array. As an integer has 4 bytes on your machine, counter gets multiplied by 4, which is the same as left shifting it by 2 - but the left shift is faster on many processors, which is why it's chosen over the multiply.

Comment: @DominikAntal dev c++

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`var_D8` is your `int arr[50]`.

You can recognize it quickly solely by its name : 50 * sizeof(int) = 200 = 0xC8. The next variable on the stack is `numb_of_elements` which is positionned on -0x10 on the stack, thus we have some memory between -0xD8 and -0x10 that corresponds to the `int` array.

Here are some explanations about the following instructions :

```
lea eax, [ebp+var_D8]  ; Get the address of the first element of the array.
mov edx, [ebp+Counter] ; Get the current element index.
shl edx, 2             ; Since the size of each element of the array is 4, multiply the index by 4
add eax, edx           ; &arr[i] = The address of the current element
mov [esp], eax         ; Move it on the stack so it can be written by std::cin
```

Comment: Great explanation, What is the additional 16 bits between `0x10` and `0xD8` used for?

Comment: @Vlad: what 16 bits? A statement that possibly needs reminding you that not any value here is in "bits" – but maybe you confused it with *bytes*. Still: how did you come to the conclusion that there is *any* additional space left between `0x10` and `0xD8`? That space is **exactly** the amount needed for the 50 integers that your original code says there should be, nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 5):

The `var_d8` is the base position of `arr` in the stack, the size of type `int` in your machine is `4`, so the position of `arr[i]` in the stack is calculated by:

> var_d8 + 4 * i